# How To print composit element in twig file

Tags: 8, webforms

I have my twig file for theming pdf submission. In my webform there is a "custom composite" element with three fields, is multivalue and I set to display it as table.

Now, I must to print it in my twig file but I don't know how.

Comment: What Twig file? Have you tried Twig debugging already?

Comment: I'm using entity_print module with webform for theming webform_submission: entity-print--webform-submission--test.html.twig. I can print any simple data with this: {{ data. first name }} or {{ data.field1 }} but I don't know how to print a compost element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution for my scenario and post it if can help anyone.
So, my "custom composite" element is multivalue and for print it in my custom entity-print--webform-submission--test.html.twig file I have insert this code:

```
{% for item in data.my_custom_composite %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{ item.day|date('d.m.Y') }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.from }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.to }}</td>
              </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```